# Is it possible to not use select operation with xquery in ms sql?

Tags: sql-server, xquery

This is my query:

```
SELECT n.c.value('(for $x in @serial[1]
        let $P := Price[1]
        where $P < 10000
        return $x
        )','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'serial',

        n.c.value('(for $x in (Type)[1] 
        let $P := Price[1]
        where $P < 10000
        return $x
        )','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Type',

        n.c.value('(for $x in (Manufacturer)[1]
        let $P := Price[1]
        where $P < 10000
        return $x
        )','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Manufacturer',

        n.c.value('(for $x in (Price)[1]
        let $P := Price[1]
        where $P < 10000
        return $x
        )','VARCHAR(100)') AS 'Price'
FROM Appliance_records as s
Cross Apply s.appliance_xml.nodes('/Appliances/Appliance') n(c)
```

Our professor wants us to use xquery in ms sql without using the select operation

Comment: Sure, update/merge + OUTPUT clause or variable + PRINT

Comment: @lad2025 can you tell me in detail pls? thanks

Comment: Without data and schema, no.

Comment: Nobody around here is going to do your homework for you. Hopefully you were paying attention in class. I am sure the professor discussed this, or is looking to see what your level of understanding is.